# Oracle extract json fields with oracle regexp_substr

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm using Oracle query with regexp_substr to extract json fields from JSON string. I would like just number(1177) of  "pickupLocation": "1177" but I'm using this query didn't work

```
select  to_char(regexp_substr(a.input_msg, '(\w*)("pickupLocation":")(\w*)(")',1,1)) 
from td_interface_phxsale_log a
```

output from my query  : "pickupLocation":"1177"

myjson data :

```
{
  "shiptoAddr": "",
  "shippingCostAmt": "",
  "pickupLocation": "1177"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not attempt to parse JSON content using regular expressions.  Assuming you really needed to go down this path, you could try:

```sql
SELECT regexp_substr(input_msg, '"pickupLocation": "([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM td_interface_phxsale_log;
```

### Demo

Note: Since JSON is already text, there is no need to convert what you extract using `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: thank you so much. Note: Since JSON is already text, there is no need to convert what you extract using TO_CHAR. >>> my field type is clob

Answer (score 2):

Why using regular expressions? That makes absolutely no sense. You pay a lot of money for your Oracle license, use the JSON tools included with it.

```
with
  inputs (my_json_input) as (
    select to_clob('{
                      "shiptoAddr": "",
                      "shippingCostAmt": "",
                      "pickupLocation": "1177"
                    }')
    from   dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only; 
-- remove the WITH clause and use your actual table and column names below)
--
select json_value(my_json_input, '$.pickupLocation') as pickuplocation
from   inputs
;

PICKUPLOCATION 
---------------
1177
```

You don't need `to_char()` here; even when the JSON string is CLOB, `json_value()` returns `varchar2` (unless explicitly requested otherwise with the `returning` clause).

If in fact the "pickup location" data type is `number` (as apparently it should be), you can stick `returning number` at the end of the `json_value()` call (before the closing parenthesis).